# Graph API not send feed to friends when publish user message on Page Wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When user post a message on Page Wall, their friends can see the update on their feeds. But when I use Graph API to post on the Page Wall on behalf of user, the message only appear on the Page Wall, but not their friends wall. More strange is that the user's wall is not updated with the new message.

The user liked the Page. I can publish feed to him through Graph API as Page Admin. 
I wonder if such behavior is controlled by facebook.